# How is MOSFET modelled in DC analysis?

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, simulation

I am wondering how simulator (LTspice, Cadence,...) compute DC operating point of MOSFET in DC analysis.
I know that in DC analysis, capacitors are open and inductors are short. 
With MOSFET how is it modelled in DC analysis?

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple answer to this question because there are many different ways to model a MOSFET. Especially for integrated circuit design very sophisticated models like BSIM or PSP are used.

For discrete circuit design often simpler models are used, the most basic and well-known being the Shichman-Hodges model, that uses simple descriptions for the cut-off linear and saturation region.

For all these models Google should bring up a number of references.

Comment: Thank you. So for SPICE LEVEL 1 here for MOSFET in DC analysis, all capacitors are open so the model is only Rs, ID and RD in series, right?
https://people.rit.edu/lffeee/SPICE_MOSFET_Models.pdf

Comment: For a DC analysis capacitors are generally removed from the circuit. The most important property is the drain-current, that has to be calculated depending on the voltages of the four terminals of the MOS transistor. To this end it is often required to calculate values for the threshold voltage, the mobility and other parameters that finally determine the current.